# How to set Entitlements for Microsoft office apps?

Tags: macos, cocoa, applescript

I am crating files of Microsoft office word, excel and powerpoint using apple script in Mac OS app. I need an AppleScript in my app with enabled sandbox. I found example code on apple developer side but How can use same code for Microsoft office.

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.mail</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.mail.compose</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

Is anybody know the correct entitlements record in XCode for Microsoft office?
What should i set in `<array> </array>` tags?

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.microsoft.Word</key>
    <array></array>
    <key>com.microsoft.Excel</key>
    <array></array>
    <key>com.microsoft.Powerpoint</key>
    <array></array>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it only works with

```
com.apple.security.temporary-exception.apple-events
```

even if "scripting-target" should be the preferred way according to apple docs

The values in your example are correct.